# Progressive measurability of a specific set related to Brownian motion

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\{W_t: t \in R_+\} $ be a standard Brownian motion process on a given probability space.
I am interested in assessing the progressive measurability of the following set:
$Z(\omega) := \{t: W_t(\omega) \not= 0\}.$

I can see that the set $Z(\omega) $ is open and that I can therefore write it as a countable union of open sets (which would be basically the excursion time intervals between the times the process hits 0). However, I cannot seem to produce a rigorous argument to prove that the set above is progressive.

I think this example is due to Meyer or Dellacherie and Meyer and it is meant to supply an example of a process that is progressive and not optional. I have known it for some time, but now I would like to fill all the steps.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you write the definition of progressive measurability?

Comment: Hello David, progressive measurability is a special case of product measurability (a subset indeed). It requires the notion of filtration.                                                       Given a filtered space $(\Omega, {\cal F} , \mathbb{F}=\{{\cal F}_t: t \in R_+\}, P) $ a stochastic process $X_t(\omega) \equiv X(t, \omega) $ is progressive measurable if it is product measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}([0, t])\otimes {\cal F}_t $. It is a special case (a subset actually) of the class of product measurable, i.e., ${\cal{B}(R)\otimes {\cal F}$-measurable events.

Comment: But what do you mean by progressive measurability of a (random) set $Z(\omega) \subset (0,\infty)$?

Comment: Well I mean that it is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\cal{B}([0, t])\otimes {\cal F}_t $ as a function from $[0, t]\times\Omega \mapsto R. $ You can think of it as trying to prove that $Y(t, \omega) := 1_{\{s \in R: W_s(\omega) \not 0\}} $ is measurable with respect to that $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I understand that, for example, if you are given the process $Y_t = 1_{\{W_t > 0\}} $ then you can create a sequence of processes such as $Y_{n,t} = (W_t \wedge 1)_+^{1/n}. $ Now $Y_{n, t} $ is continuous and adapted (for the standard filtration) and therefore progressively measurable. Then, since $\lim_n Y_{n,t} = Y_t $ we are done. So, I wonder if I could treat the example I am asking about in the same way, considering the case of $W_t < 0 $ and $W_t>0, $ separately... It gets a little fuzzy for me.

Comment: @Mauric: The set in question is actually optional (in fact, it is predictable).

Answer (score 5):

This follows from two quite standard results.

- All continuous and adapted processes are predictable.
- All predictable processes are progressively measurable.

So $W$, and hence $Z=W^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$, is progressively measurable. However, as predictable processes are also optional, the set in question is optional. It, therefore, does not provide an example of a progressively measurable set which is not optional.

For an example of a set which is progressively measurable but not optional, take the set of left limit points of the connected components of $Z$. That is, take the set of points $(t,\omega)\in([0,\infty)\times\Omega)\setminus Z$ for which $(t,t+\epsilon)\times\{\omega\}\subset Z$ for some $\epsilon\gt0$ (depending on $t$ and $\omega$). It can be seen that this is progressively measurable but not optional from the optional projection theorem. In fact, the optional projection of its indicator function is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T>0$ and define $$Y(t,\omega) := 1_{Z(\omega)}(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & W_t(\omega) \neq 0 \\ 0 & W_t(\omega) = 0 \end{cases}$$ for $t \in [0,T]$, $\omega \in \Omega$. Then

$$[Y=0] = \{(t,\omega); t \leq T, W_t(\omega) = 0\} = [W=0] \cap ([0,T] \times \Omega)$$

Since the Brownian motion $W$ is progressively measurable, we conclude that

$$[Y=0] \in \mathcal{B}[0,T] \otimes \mathcal{F}_T$$

By definition, $Y$ does only attain the values $0$ and $1$, thus

$$Y:([0,T] \times \Omega,\mathcal{B}[0,T] \otimes \mathcal{F}_T) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$$ is measurable.

**Notation** $$[W=0] := \{(t,\omega) \in [0,\infty) \times \Omega; W(t,\omega)=0\}$$

Comment: Thank you Saz. You managed to make my argument rigorous. And thank you to George Lowther for his insightful reply which actually tackle the problem without even doing any "calculation".